# iOS unit tests fail on CocoaPods Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Since migrating our code base to Swift 3 using Xcode 8 we've been unable to get our unit tests to run. The app compiles and archives fine for the store, but when we try to run tests it fails to build complaining of:

framework not found GoogleMapsBase for architecture x86_64

I've checked our podfile and everything appears to be set correctly according to the latest documentation.

Edit: Podfile below

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target "Borked" do
    platform :ios, '9.3'
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

    target "Unit Tests" do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

    target "UI Tests" do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you please post your Podfile?  Are you sure you are linking the Google Maps framework with the test target?

Comment: I've tried multiple variations...inheriting from the main target, splitting them out into separate ones and hard coding the dependencies. No matter which way I slice them up it still fails.

Comment: Can you update your cocoapods and update the pods by Pods install and check it?

Comment: Everything is up to date with cocoapods and the frameworks I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work!

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '9.3'
    use_frameworks!

    target 'MyApp' do

         pod 'GoogleMaps'
         pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

         target "Unit Tests" do
           inherit! :search_paths
         end

         target "UI Tests" do
           inherit! :search_paths
         end 
    end
```

or this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.3'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do

 target 'MyExtension' do

     pod 'GoogleMaps'
     pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

     target "Unit Tests" do
       inherit! :search_paths
     end

     target "UI Tests" do
       inherit! :search_paths
     end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Oh wait - the second form worked! I had to explicitly place the Google Maps pod into each target for some reason. Thanks!